# MSBuild AppXBundle for x86 and x64

Tags: msbuild, windows, appx

I want to build a *.**appxbundle** for a Windows 8.1 JavaScript app which contains the **x86** AND **x64** appx.

This is working fine on Visual Studio 2013. I right click on the project and choose *Store*->*Create app packages* and then pick both architectures.

However I can't get it working on MSBuild. My msbuild statement looks like this:

```
msbuild MyProj.Win81.jsproj /property:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64;AppxBundle=Always /target:Clean,Rebuild,Publish
```

My *MyProj.Win81.jsproj* looks like this (shortened a bit):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|AnyCPU">
  <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
  <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
</ProjectConfiguration>
<ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|ARM">
  <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
  <Platform>ARM</Platform>
</ProjectConfiguration>
<ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
  <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
  <Platform>x64</Platform>
</ProjectConfiguration>
<ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x86">
  <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
  <Platform>x86</Platform>
</ProjectConfiguration>
<ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|AnyCPU">
  <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
  <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
</ProjectConfiguration>
<ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|ARM">
  <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
  <Platform>ARM</Platform>
</ProjectConfiguration>
<ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
  <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
  <Platform>x64</Platform>
</ProjectConfiguration>
<ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x86">
  <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
  <Platform>x86</Platform>
</ProjectConfiguration>
</ItemGroup>
  <Import Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" />
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '' or '$(VisualStudioVersion)' &lt; '12.0'">
    <VisualStudioVersion>12.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\$(WMSJSProjectDirectory)\Microsoft.VisualStudio.$(WMSJSProject).Default.props" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\$(WMSJSProjectDirectory)\Microsoft.VisualStudio.$(WMSJSProject).props" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetPlatformIdentifier>Windows</TargetPlatformIdentifier>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>8.1</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <RequiredPlatformVersion>8.1</RequiredPlatformVersion>
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>12.0</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
    <DefaultLanguage>en-US</DefaultLanguage>
    <AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>False</AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
    <AppxBundlePlatforms>x86|x64</AppxBundlePlatforms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <AppxManifest Include="package.win81.store.appxmanifest">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AppxManifest>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\$(WMSJSProjectDirectory)\Microsoft.VisualStudio.$(WMSJSProject).targets" />
</Project>
```

MSBuild will always generate a appxbundle which only includes the x64 architecture. This might be because I explicitly set Platform=x64, although AppxBundlePlatforms defines both. If I leave out the Platform parameter I run into a error:

```
error APPX3104: You cannot create an app bundle when building for platform 'AnyCPU' which is not included in the list of platforms selected for producting app bundle. Set platform to a one of following values: x86;x64.
```

What am I missing?

// *edit*: here a screenshot of VS2013 appxbundle creation and updated project configuration of jsproj file
[image]

Comment: What is the configuration and platform when you build from Visual Studio?

Comment: added configuration of jsproj file above. On VS it is Release|x86 and Release|x64 (see image )

Comment: Try with `AppxBundlePlatforms=x86|x64` in property as argument of mSBuild command line

Comment: same result, only x64 appx is on appxbundle :/

Comment: well, use 3 command lines : one for build x86, one for build x64 and one for publish

Comment: found error. I also changed the property AppxPackageName with a custom value on my jsproj. If I leave out property everything works as expected